# how can I force users to use two factor authentication with MSAL angular?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, two-factor-authentication, azure-authentication, msal-angular

I am trying to implement two-factor sign in using msal-angular, I want to force users to use two factor authentication, preferably Authenticator App.

So far I only managed to configure it the way users only required to enter password.

my settings:

```
const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;


export const protectedResourceMap: [string, string[]][] = [
  ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
        clientId: '*******',
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/*****/',
        validateAuthority: true,
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
      },
    },
      {
        popUp: !isIE,
        consentScopes: [
          'user.read',
          'openid',
          'profile',
          'api://**********/access_as_user'
        ],
        unprotectedResources: ['https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/'],
        protectedResourceMap,
        extraQueryParameters: {}
      }
    )
  ],
  declarations: [

  ],
  providers: [
    MsalLoginService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class MsalLoginModule { }
```

due to angular version I use msal-angilar@1.1.2
here is my code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MsalLoginService {
  loginDisplay = false;

  constructor(
    private broadcastService: BroadcastService,
    private authService: MsalService
  ) {
    this.checkoutAccount();

    this.authService.handleRedirectCallback((authError, response) => {
      if (authError) {
        console.error('Redirect Error: ', authError.errorMessage);
        return;
      }

      console.log('Redirect Success: ', response);
    });

    this.authService.setLogger(new Logger((logLevel, message, piiEnabled) => {
      console.log('MSAL Logging: ', message);
    }, {
      correlationId: CryptoUtils.createNewGuid(),
      piiLoggingEnabled: false
    }));

  }

  checkoutAccount() {
    this.loginDisplay = !!this.authService.getAccount();
  }

  loginPopup(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((subscriber) => {

      this.authService.loginPopup({ scopes: ['user.read'], prompt: 'select_account' }).then(res => {
        this.authService.acquireTokenSilent({ scopes: ['user.read'] }).then((response: any) => {
          // send token for validation on server
          subscriber.next(response);
        }).catch(ex => subscriber.error(ex));
      }).catch(ex => subscriber.error(ex));

    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

}
```

just in case although I suppose the problem is in the setting in Azure.

Edit:
There are several ways to force multi-factor login through the Azure Portal, however most of them are visible only through paid/trial account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can force users to use two factor authentication with MSAL angular. Your [angular configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code) is looking OK. Now you need to recheck your azure configurations. You can configure your settings [here](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks).